# Openshift node.js phantom GET requests

Tags: node.js, openshift, sails.js

I just started logging all requests to an Openshift node instance,

It's getting hit with a GET/ request every ~10 seconds and req.headers.origin is undefined

Less frequent when I don't call next()

```
'/*': function (req, res, next) {
  console.log( "Route " + req.method + ":" + req.url + " " + req.headers.origin);
  if( typeof req.headers.origin !== 'undefined') {
    return next();
  }
}
```

Comment: I wonder if it has any relation to [this](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/2012#issuecomment-50227048)...

Comment: you set "scaling" for this app on openshift? Than is surely the Loadblancer

Comment: Thanks for those answers.  Makes sense.  Scary.

Comment: Yes, the Loadblancer check the status of every server in your stack with a HTTP-Request to make sure he don't redirect a user to a server that isn't available.

Comment: It is infact HAproxy (the Loadbalancer) checking the status of your application. Since you guys came up with the answer I would suggest posting in in the answer field so the question can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 1):

Those are requests from the HAProxy making sure that your gears are still alive.  You can change the frequency of them by sshing into your application and editing the ~/haproxy/haproxy.cfg file if you like.  Otherwise just ignore them.